# Function is not defined in Python

Tags: python

I have the following error when I run this program: NameError: name create is not defined. I`m trying to creeate a library program to add/remove/see all the books and everything will be stored in a .dat file
I defined the function, but I'm not sure why it's not working. I copied the code below:

```
import pickle
import os

class Library:
    def __init__(self,book ,title,author,pubdate,status,retdate,location):
        self.book = book
        self.title = title
        self.author = author
        self.pubdate = pubdate
        self.status = status
        self.retdate = retdate
        self.location = location

    def details(self):
        self.details = " Title: " + self.title + " Author: " + self.author + " Publication date: " + str(self.pubdate) + " Status" + self.status + " Return date : " + str(self.retdate) + "location" + str(self.location)
        print(self.details)


        def create(self):
        harvard_lib = Library(self.title, self.author, self.pubdate, self.status, self.retdate, self.location)
        self.location = 1
        while index !="Q" : 
            book = str(input("Book:"))
            title = str(input("Enter the title of the book: "))
            author = str(input("Enter the author of the book: "))
            pubdate = int(input("Enter the publication date of the book: "))
            status = str(input("Enter the status of the book(A / N):  ")) # a-available, n- not
            retdate = int(input("Enter the return date of the book: "))
            index = str(input("Press any key to continue,or pres Q to quit"))
            location +=1

        booklist = 'booklist.dat'
        newitem = []

        if os.path.exists(booklist):
            with open(booklist,'rb') as rfp: 
                newitem = pickle.load(rfp)

        newitem1 = book,title,author,pubdate,status,retdate,index,location
        newitem.append(newitem1)

        with open(booklist,'wb') as wfp:
            pickle.dump(newitem, wfp)

        with open(booklist,'rb') as rfp:
            newitem = pickle.load(rfp)

        print(newitem)

harvard_lib.create()
```

Comment: Check the edit. Create an instance of Library class and then call the method like this: obj = Library(...); obj.create()

Comment: There are other problems in your code, rather than asked question. What it seems, you have file with your books, which is pickled list of tuples. So when you initiate class Library, you don't need to have self.book/title etc. What you need instead is self.path where book is stored. So you create library like harvard_lib = Library('booklist.dat'). Then you need method to add book, which is your current method create, then you will need to write other methods to retrieve information from it.

Answer (score 2):

`create()` is a method of `Library` class, not a function.
If you want to access a method of a class, you need an `instance` of that class.

Try something like that:

```py
harvard_lib = Library("bookname", "title", ...)
harvard_lib.create()
```

Comment: I`ve tried with harvard_lib.create() but it`s still telling me that it`s not defined. You can see my edit to the original code

Comment: @John You need to create a `Library` instance first. Try to put both of the two lines that @T.M Luan added.And I suggest you to take a look at Object Oriented Programming in Python. You can go through this tutorial: https://realpython.com/python3-object-oriented-programming/

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an instance of the class first before you can make use of that method. It is a method of a class so you should not treat it as a normal function.

```
hash_lib = Library("Lord of the Rings","J.R Tolkien",...) #creating a class instance
hash_lib.create() #making use of the class method
```

with this you should be good to go